# Is it possible to use an SSD for the RAM preview in After Effects CC?

Tags: after-effects, preview, ssd

I'm looking at my options, I would like to buy an SSD to do RAM previews with but I'm not sure if it can be configured this way... is there anyone else that has tried this?

Comment: SSD is not as fast as RAM is. Here's a relevant question: http://superuser.com/q/617864/141595

Answer (score 2):

An SSD is a replacement for a hard drive, not a replacement for RAM.

RAM previews are rendered into your computer's system RAM, not to internal storage (and then you can save the RAM preview to disk if you wish).

Having said that, I recently replaced a 7200rpm internal hard drive in my macbook pro, and added some more RAM. It makes a huge difference to the speed of loading and saving, and seems to improve render times to some extent too. It's like buying a new computer- I would definitely recommend it.